# Rails unobtrusive AJAX views: using same controller action and js.erb file for different views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are a lot of great tutorials on the web about using unobtrusive javascript (jquery-ujs) to create AJAX Rails views that update without a page refresh ([example](https://launchschool.com/blog/the-detailed-guide-on-how-ajax-works-with-ruby-on-rails)).

The gist of it is that you use `respond_to |format|` && `format.js` in your controller, and then build javascript files like `create.js.erb`, `update.js.erb` and `destroy.js.erb`, which use jQuery to replace the HTML of a container with a rendered partial.

So, for example, `destroy.js.erb` has something like `$('#table').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "table") %>');` to re-render the now updated index.html.erb partial table.

It's brilliant and easy, and I love using it.

The problem is all this simplicity starts to fade away as soon as I have to perform the same action (for example, the `destroy` action) from 2 different views.

For example: not only a delete can happen from `index.html.erb`, but it can also happen from `dashboard.html.erb` (different action/view), which has a different HTML structure and doesn't even have a `<div id="table">` to begin with.

If I want to re-render dashboard.html.erb, I can't simply use `render: :dashboard` in my Controller, because I'm on `destroy` action, and it doesn't have all the logic and instance variables needed for `dashboard.html.erb`. Of course I wouldn't repeat myself, but extracting all the `dashboard` action logic to a private method and calling it in both `dashboard` and `destroy` actions doesn't seem a best practice.

I'm having the same headaches with `update.js.erb`. There are now multiple views that have `remote:true` links that update my models, and I'm seeing myself passing extra params (like `params:{source: 'name_of_current_view}') in the link_to links and creating a lot of if/else in the controllers to render the correct javascript response.

What is the best practice to deal with these situations?

Comment: Can you post the code for `dashboard.html.erb`?

Comment: @Pavan It's a very complex file, but imagine that in the dashboard my models are listed in a small widget, instead of a table, and doesn't share the same columns at all.